# How to find Ship Transverse Metacentic Height

Tags: stability, ships

I did a Civil Engineering course some years ago and from my textbook I had this question. I found that a very interesting question, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution to this. 
I encourage people to put comments up, but ideally I would be appreciative if the comments are related as to how you do the calculation process to get to the answer.

**The half ordinates of the contour of the load water plane of a ship of 2,800 metric tons displacement, measured at intervals of 6 m, are 0.30, 3.33, 5.07, 6.18, 6.75, 6.90, 6.75, 6.18, 5.61, 4.47, 0.60 m respectively.
If the centre of gravity is 1.87 m above the centre of buoyancy, calculate the transverse metacentric height.
Sea water has a density of 1,025 kg/m^3.**

Also, just wondering how you would best Explain the relation between metacentre and curve of buoyancy as vessel heals over.

[image: My Calculations (Ship Transverse Metacentric Height)]

Comment: What have you done so far? If you show some effort... Have you applied the process given here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29643/10902

Comment: @SolarMike 
i have tried to find an answer from from Question 4 example on pages e42 to e44 on this website https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780080982373/downloads/appendix_E_questions_and_answers.pdf.
The question asks for transverse GM = Transverse BM - BG
and we are given BG = 1.87 m
From doing the calculations I got BM =1.958 m, so the difference = 1.958 - 1.87 = 0.088 m . That is not correct as answer in textbook is 0.74 m.

Comment: @SolarMike

I have found with previous post that I have done, that if I put the answer up first it seems to discourage some people from giving me a comment or they give me one comment and if I want to clarify something, then I never hear from them again.
So this is why I have done it the way I have.
I am creating a website on cruise ships at the moment and this is an activity on the side, so I want to get it sorted out as quickly as I can.
I hope you understand.
I may also want to do a website on these sort of calculations in the future as well and knowing them will help with that.

Comment: Well, up to you, just that questions that show effort seem to be better received...  BTW vessels "heel" as in keel, they don't tend to heal...

Comment: @SolarMike
I have done calcs in Excel and copied them here.
Now we can discuss calcs I have tried to get to answer. You can see from my calcs, I got 0.84 m for Transverse metacentric height and textbook answer is 0.74 m.
So question now is, is 0.84 m correct or 0.74 m?
Are you guys experts on Ship Stability, if you are then, I'd kindly appreciate your feedback to my questions.
If you don't know this, but know someone that understands this really well, then I'd be really appreciative if they could check over my calcs and see if they can get 0.74 m like textbook answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat
I have done calcs in Excel and copied them here.
Now we can discuss calcs I have tried to get to answer. You can see from my calcs, I got 0.84 m for Transverse metacentric height and textbook answer is 0.74 m.
So question now is, is 0.84 m correct or 0.74 m?
Are you guys experts on Ship Stability, if you are then, I'd kindly appreciate your feedback to my questions.
If you don't know this, but know someone that understands this really well, then I'd be really appreciative if they could check over my calcs and see if they can get 0.74 m like textbook answer.

Comment: @SolarMike
Are you guys going to reply to me about what I have asked?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat
Are you guys going to reply to me about what I have asked?

Comment: @SolarMike
 You are the perfect example of what I mentioned, give me one comment and if I want to clarify something, then I never hear from you again.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat
 You are the perfect example of what I mentioned, give me one comment and if I want to clarify something, then I never hear from you again.

Comment: As you mentioned that you are going to publish this on your own website as how to deal with this type of problem, perhaps some of us feel that you should be capable of solving this...

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat
Hi thank you very much for checking over my answer, showing me how you have come up with the same answer as me and that the text book is a bit out, much appreciated.
Bit of a misunderstanding, sorry if I offended, I thought that both yourself and Solar Mike were not going to reply to me, but you've proven my thoughts wrong.
As you mentioned I have posted a few questions up, but I don't really want to go around in circles too much with working them out, because I'm busy. We are on this forum to help each other out .
Did you use Excel  to do the calculations and the graph?